# How to store information from JSON files in cache using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script that is called every x minutes to parse a JSON file.

The JSON contains data points with an ID. I want to be able to see if I encountered an ID in a previous run of the script so that I can append the information contained in my data point to my old data with the same ID.

In order to do this I want to store the data as a key value pair in cache. The key in this case being the ID and the value the rest of the information contained in the JSON. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem description and add code of what you have tried. As it currently stands this question is too broad. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *Ring* helps your problem. https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

When your function looks like this:

```
def your_function(data_id):
    return ...
```

*Ring* is adaptable like this:

```
import ring

storage = {}

@ring.dict(storage, expire=60)  # 60 seconds cache in `storage` dict
def your_function(data_id):
    return ...
```

They will be stored in `storage` dict (unless you kill the process).
If you want to keep the cache even after killing your process, something like `@ring.memcache` or `@ring.redis` will help you.

Comment: Not recommended for production. [ref](https://ring-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ring/func_sync.html#ring.func.sync.dict)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a sqlite db, but you could as easily use another json file to keep a running tally of IDs encountered. I don't think you're going to easily keep it in memory and access between python sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Conventionally, the data structure you would use in this case is a [hash map/hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), where the ID could be your key and the value a hash of the serialized data-

Seeing that dictionaries in python are actually implemented using hash tables, the question whether or not it is actually worth the effort, as opposed to just parsing the whole thing every time and rebuilding the object you retrieve, depends on what exactly you are trying to do with the data and how much data it is.

If you are looking for a key-value based storage, to add persistence to your python script, a no-sql approach(such as [mongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)) should be a good fit.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that the json is replaced by a new one regularly. So parsing the Json twice will not help since I will not 'remember' which ID's I already encountered.

Comment: In that case: 1.) Parse the JSON on every individual run 2.) store it in MongoDB 3.) retrieve the data on the next run 4.) Parse the new JSON file 5.) Append new entries and overwrite/handle re-encountered IDs